@cypress/code-coverage Unexpected token (win?.__coverage__)

I have installed "@cypress/code-coverage": "^3.12.39",
And added import "@cypress/code-coverage/support"; in ui/e2e/cypress/support/e2e.js
And added require("@cypress/code-coverage/task")(on, config); under setupNodeEvents(on, config) in ui/e2e/cypress.config.js

while running Cypress and click on the test file getting the following error
 ./node_modules/@cypress/code-coverage/support.js 70:44
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (70:44)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     const saveCoverageObject = (win) => {
|       // if application code has been instrumented, the app iframe "window" has an object
>       const applicationSourceCoverage = win?.__coverage__
|       if (!applicationSourceCoverage) {
|         return
 @ ./cypress/support/e2e.js 55:0-40
 @ multi ./cypress/support/e2e.js


have you found a solution? '?' is relatively newer operator and it's not expected there, but I don't know a good way of fixing this.

I ran into this error today. Downgrading to an older version seems to get me around it for now. Using version 3.12.32 seems to work for me.
This is what I see in support.js on version 3.12.32.
const saveCoverageObject = (win) => {
  // if application code has been instrumented, the app iframe "window" has an object
  const applicationSourceCoverage = win.__coverage__
  if (!applicationSourceCoverage)
    return

Seems the latest version is not playing nice with the optional chaining operator
const applicationSourceCoverage = win?.__coverage__

I am currently using @jsdevtools/coverage-istanbul-loader. Not sure if using a different loader would handle the operator better. The error seems to indicate it might. I'm just not sure what loader I would need to use. So downgrading is what I am doing for now...
I opened a ticket on github for this as well.
https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage/issues/866
